# Dismiss SwiftUI macOS sidebar NavigationLink detail view with default view

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

I created a sample macOS 10.15 SwiftUI app that shows a sidebar and detail information about the selected item. As of the documentation a navigation view needs the `List` at the first position, a `View` in my case a `Text` if the list is empty, and another default `View` that is shown when no item is selected.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var selection: String?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SidebarView(selection: $selection)
            Text("Empty List")
            DefaultView()
        }
    }
}
```

My first approach was creating a `@State` variable `selection` that holds the current selection, which is then used by the `List`. Usually I want to use a `ForEach` inside with sections, but for the sake of simplicity I used this approach.

```
struct SidebarView: View {

    @State var elements = ["A","B","C"]
    @Binding var selection: String?

    var body: some View {
        List(elements, id: \.self, selection: _selection) { element in
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(element: element, selection: _selection), tag: element, selection: _selection, label: {
                Text(element)
            })
        }
    }    
}
```

The default view is just a basic `View`:

```
struct DefaultView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("I am the default view")
            .background(Color.orange)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

For testing the "clearing-functionality`I added a simply`Button` in the detail view, which is shown when a list element is selected:

```
struct DetailView: View {

    let element: String?
    @Binding var selection: String?

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text(element ?? "None selected")
                Button(action: { selection = nil }) {
                    Text("clear")
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

**What needs to be changed so that the button click actually dismisses the `NavigationLink` and shows the `DefaultView` again?**